# WORD_BIT vs LONG_BIT

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-architecture

What is the difference between `WORD_BIT` and `LONG_BIT`? And which one should I use to find out the word size of my system? Both return different results

```
➜  ~ getconf LONG_BIT
64
➜  ~ getconf WORD_BIT
32
➜  ~
```

I also read in some other post that a reliable way to find out word size can be to print the size of void. This gives me 8 bytes.

```
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(void*));
```

Will this always be equal to the result returned by `getconf LONG_BIT`?

Sorry, sneaking one more question here - word size is related to the CPU architecture. Will OS also work on the same word size that CPU architecture has defined?

Comment: `sizeof(void*)` is the size of a _pointer to_ void. "void" itself is nothing at all. But that still gives you just the pointer size, while one could have other quite reasonable definitions for the "word size".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[POSIX defines `WORD_BIT` and `LONG_BIT`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) as the number of bits in objects of types `int` and `long` respectively. The size of an object of type `void *` is the size of a pointer to data¹.

32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long` and pointers is the standard model for Linux on 64-bit x86; it’s known as LP64 (see the AMD64 extensions to the System V ABI).

There is no guaranteed link between these sizes; the only size equality guarantee C provides is that `sizeof(char)` is 1. Windows on x64 for example uses 32-bit `long` and `int`, and 64-bit pointers. (There are other size requirements: C guarantees that `sizeof(short)` ≤ `sizeof(int)` ≤ `sizeof(long)`, `short` and `int` are at least 16 bits, and `long` is at least 32 bits; POSIX additionally requires that `int` and `long` are at least 32 bits in length.)

The most significant object size in terms of matching an operating system an CPU is the pointer size (how `int` and `long` are handled is mostly a concern for the compiler), but the relationship between the operating system and the CPU’s pointer size isn’t always straightforward either. An operating system has to use a pointer size *supported* by the CPU, but CPUs can support multiple pointer sizes... For example, 64-bit x86 CPUs² can run 64-bit operating systems (Windows x64, 64-bit Linux, etc.), 32-bit operating systems (Windows x32, 32-bit Linux, OS/2, etc.), and 16-bit operating systems (such as MS-DOS). Even among 64-bit operating systems, there can be variations, as mentioned above (32-bit `long` on Windows x64, 64-bit `long` on 64-bit Linux), and even the “native” pointer size might not be what you expect (the Linux [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), and SPARC, use 32-bit pointers in user space). Historically, released versions of Windows on the 64-bit Alpha platform were 32-bit operating systems.

---

¹ In some environments (non-Unix, as far as I’m aware), pointers to data aren’t always the same size as pointers to functions.

² With appropriate firmware support, until Intel releases [X86S](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/envisioning-future-simplified-architecture.html) CPUs.

Comment: [ISO/IEC 9899:1999](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) does set some minimum lengths for int/short/long/blah although the only guaranteed relationship between types is that sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long). If you're following the standard, you don't know that an int is 32-bits but you do know that it is at least 16 bits.

Comment: @doneal24 right — that part of my answer wasn’t clear, I was thinking of strict equalities, I’ll clarify. POSIX requires bigger sizes, 32 bits at least for `int` and `long`.

Comment: I grew up with various DEC systems along with Cray and Cray-lookalikes, attached array processors, a horrible 24-bit system (we could crash it with a six-line FORTRAN program),  and various Sun M68000 and SPARC processors. Word size was something I unfortunately had to pay attention to.

Comment: Sorry ! @doneal24 woke me up with his M68000… ;-) Only to realize that last OP's question does not appear to me fully addressed :  "Will OS also work on the same word size that CPU architecture has defined?" question I would answer : almost certainly but only incidentally since… it will have been built with a compiler necessarily aware of all arch dependent misc. sizeofs…

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Is there a sure shot way of knowing the word size OS is currently working on?

Comment: @0Nicholas under Linux, run `arch` — that will give you the kernel’s “native” architecture. A 64-bit x86 kernel will say `x86_64`.

Comment: Sorry if this is too silly. But does `x86_64` always mean that OS is operating on 64 bit word? Is it possible that CPU supports both 64 bit and 32 bit, but the OS is only working on 32 bits (as you mentioned above)?

Comment: @0Nicholas yes, it’s possible; on x86 then `arch` shows `i686`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So there is no definite way to find out the word size that current OS is working on?

Comment: @0Nicholas on Linux on x86, if `arch` says `x86_64`, the kernel is running in 64-bit mode, if it says `i686`, it’s running in 32-bit mode (or running a 32-bit personality but that doesn’t matter here).

Comment: Thanks, this discussion was wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other information:
the phrase “the size of a pointer” is ambiguous. 
In the [x86 memory models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_models) “Medium” and “Compact” models,
the size of a pointer to data and the size of a pointer to code
are not the same. 
The type `void *` refers to a pointer to data.

Comment: Aargh, yes — but has there ever been a Unix-style system that made use of those memory models? (Those I‘m familiar with, pre 386, used at most one segment for code and one segment for data, with 16-bit pointers.)